# Why pointermove is lagging on the carousel with transition and mousemove not?

Tags: javascript, css

There is a self-made carousel:

```
let current = 0;

const onMouseDown = (evt) => {
    let startX = evt.pageX;
    evt.target.ondragstart = () => false;

    const onMouseMove = (evt) => {
        const diff = startX - evt.pageX;
        current += diff;
        startX = evt.pageX;
        menuList.style.transform = `translateX(${current}px)`;
    };

    const onMouseUp = () => {
        menu.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener('pointerup', onMouseUp);
    }

    document.addEventListener('pointerup', onMouseUp);
    menu.addEventListener('pointerleave', onMouseUp);
    menu.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
};


menu.addEventListener('pointerdown', onMouseDown);
```

The problem is that with mousemove transition, the carousel movement does not lag and its smooth, but with pointer just freeze and big lags.
How to fix it? I need it to work on phones as well. I want to use pointer move.

1. The user presses left mouse. pointerdown/mousedown on the carousel
2. The carousel should move relative to the mouse coordinates pointermove/mousemove.
3. There should be smoothness, which can only be set with transition, but it works crookedly with pointmove